# Connection from Test Manager to TFS 2012 team project failed

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I cannot connect from MS Test Manager to a certain TFS 2012 team project. I've two team projects: The second connected fine from Test Manager but the first one gets the error:

```
"Automatic connection to the following team project failed: ..."
```

Both team projects seems to be identical - I exported all work item types from the first one to the second one but still the second can be connected, but not the first.

What is missing or what can be the reason for the connection error for the first team project?

Thanks, Konrad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem were the categories of the project:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsmantest/thread/71ee54fd-38f4-403e-9256-268dae6e3704